# "At the age of 23, she [become] a doctor"

Tags: modal-verbs

> At the age of 23, she **will become** a doctor.
>   At the age of 23, she **became** a doctor.

Please advise which one is correct. My friend is saying "will become" is wrong.

Comment: Did it happen yet?

Comment: Perhaps also consider: *"At the age of 23, she **becomes** a doctor."*

Answer (score 8):

**She will become** means it will happen in the future.
**She became** means that it has already happened.

Both are correct. They are just different tenses - future and past respectively.